Maui ios: button events in UIImagePickerController.CameraOverlayView works on portrait but not in landscape mode
I am building a Maui app which requires custom camera view/control in order to play some audio and show some more info.
What I have so far is working as it should in portrait mode. Once my phone is in landscape mode and I open the camera, the buttons on the bottom (back, record, audio) are visible but not clickable. The flash button does work on both scenario's. It seems like there is another layer on top of the other buttons. Does anyone know what to do?
Portrait (working):

Landscape:

public partial class CustomCameraOverlayView : UIView
{

public UIButton captureButton;
public UIButton cancelButton;
public UIButton flashButton;
public UIButton playAudioButton;

private UILabel countdownLabel;
private int countdownValue = 3;
private NSTimer countdownTimer;
private readonly AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
readonly UIImagePickerController picker;
readonly UIView overlay;
private UIView markerView;

private UIProgressView progressView;
private readonly double maximumTime; // Total time for 100% progress in seconds
private readonly double minimumTime;
private int currentProgress = 0;
private NSTimer progressTimer;

nfloat buttonX;
nfloat buttonY;
readonly int buttonWidth;
readonly int buttonHeight;
readonly EventHandler cancelAction;


bool _isRecording = false;

public CustomCameraOverlayView(double max, double min, AudioPlayer audioPlayer, UIImagePickerController picker, EventHandler cancelAction) : base(picker.CameraOverlayView.Frame)
{
    maximumTime = max;
    minimumTime = min;
    countdownValue = int.Parse($"{min}");
    this.audioPlayer = audioPlayer;
    this.picker = picker;
    overlay = new();
    overlay.Frame = picker.CameraOverlayView.Frame;
    this.cancelAction = cancelAction;

    #region Remove black rect

    nfloat ratio = (nfloat)4.0 / (nfloat)3.0;
    nfloat scale;
    if (DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Orientation == DisplayOrientation.Portrait)
    {
        nfloat imageWidth = MathF.Floor((float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width * (float)ratio);
        scale = (nfloat)(Math.Ceiling(((float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Height / (float)imageWidth) * 10.0) / 10.0);
    }
    else
    {
        nfloat imageWidth = MathF.Floor((float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Height * (float)ratio);
        scale = (nfloat)(Math.Ceiling(((float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width / (float)imageWidth) * 10.0) / 10.0);
    }

    picker.CameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(scale, scale);
    #endregion


    buttonWidth = 60;
    buttonHeight = 60;
    buttonX = (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - buttonWidth) / 2;
    buttonY = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height - buttonHeight - 50;
    GetXYPositions();
    Initialize();
    picker.CameraOverlayView = overlay;
}

void GetXYPositions()
{
    if (DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Orientation == DisplayOrientation.Portrait)
    {
        buttonX = (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - buttonWidth) / 2;
        buttonY = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height - buttonHeight - 50;
    }
    else
    {
        buttonX = (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height - buttonWidth) / 2;
        buttonY = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - buttonHeight - 50;
        //overlay.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation((nfloat)Math.PI/2);
    }
}

public void Initialize()
{
    AddButtons();
    AddProgressbar();

    AddTimeCode();
    //AddSubview(overlay);
}

void AddButtons()
{
    // Cancel Button
    cancelButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
    cancelButton.SetImage(new UIImage(NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("back", "png")), UIControlState.Normal);

    cancelButton.Frame = new CGRect(buttonX / 3, buttonY + 7, buttonWidth - 15, buttonHeight - 15);

    cancelButton.TouchUpInside += cancelAction;
    cancelButton.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

    overlay.Add(cancelButton);


    // Capture button
    captureButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
    captureButton.SetImage(new UIImage(NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("startrecording", "png")), UIControlState.Normal);

    captureButton.Frame = new CGRect(buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);

    captureButton.TouchUpInside += CaptureButtonClicked;
    captureButton.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

    overlay.Add(captureButton);

    if (audioPlayer != null)
    {
        // Audioplayer button
        playAudioButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
        playAudioButton.SetImage(new UIImage(NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("audio-msg", "png")), UIControlState.Normal);

        playAudioButton.Frame = new CGRect((buttonX / 3) * 5 + 10, buttonY + 7, buttonWidth - 15, buttonHeight - 15);

        playAudioButton.TouchUpInside += PlayAudioBtnClicked;
        playAudioButton.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

        audioPlayer.AudioPlayerInstance.FinishedPlaying += FinishedPlaying;

        overlay.Add(playAudioButton);
    }

    // Flash button
    flashButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
    flashButton.SetImage(new UIImage(NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("flash-off", "png")), UIControlState.Normal);
    var flashButtonY = 20;
    flashButton.Frame = new CGRect(buttonX / 6, flashButtonY, buttonWidth - 15, buttonHeight - 15);

    flashButton.TouchUpInside += FlashButtonClicked;
    flashButton.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

    overlay.Add(flashButton);
}

}

After setting a breakpoint on          playAudioButton.TouchUpInside += PlayAudioBtnClicked;, will clicking the button in landscape mode trigger the breakpoint?

@SeanHe-MSFT the event assignment itself is triggerd (playAudioButton.TouchUpInside += PlayAudioBtnClicked; ) but clicking the button wont trigger the event itself (PlayAudioBtnClicked())

What makes me wonder is why you need to set the button positions for horizontal and vertical screens respectively for the camera, because based on the screenshots, even if you don’t set the button position to adjust the horizontal screen, it will not change, so you can try to cancel the button position setting in horizontal and vertical screen respectively.

@SeanHe-MSFT I had to otherwise you could only see the cancelButton in the middle of the screen. I found out the UIImagePickerController was always in portrait mode for some reason. After overriding GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations() method, the whole view is in landscape. So the buttons are now on the left side of the device (volume buttons side) when in landscape mode. I can live with that for now. But what I want to solve now is the UI not responding when switching between landscape and portrait. The orientation stays alwasy the same as the initial orientation when creating the view.

If you don't override the GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations() method, set the breakpoint in the GetXYPositions() method, the code won't run else{} when the screen is rotated, right?

If I open the camera while the phone is in landscape then it will run the else.

I think adding GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations() affects the running of the program. You can try not to apply this method first, hit the breakpoint at GetXYPositions() in the original code, and check whether this method will be run when the screen is inverted. This can check whether the program recognizes the screen inverted, and this may be why the button is not clickable.

Or you can provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example to help me reproduce your problem.

@SeanHe-MSFT Thanks for your support. I got it working now. The problem was that the overlay rotated to landscape but kept the portrait frame dimensions. This caused the overlay to be only on the left side of the screen, while the buttons where outside of the frame. I fixed it with the following: DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfoChanged += InfoChanged; and in InfoChanged I do: overlay.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Height);
picker.CameraOverlayView.Frame = overlay.Frame;

Congratulations! I'm glad the problem was solved.
